# What does "docker pull" do step by step?

Tags: docker

When I try to pull jupyter/datascience-notebook image,it shows different status of layers that it needed,for example:

```
471db38bcfbf: Already exists 
0b4aba487617: Already exists 
d44ea0cd796c: Pull complete 
5ac827d588be: Pull complete 
a653dc992384: Download complete
```

1. What are the differences between `Pull complete` and `Download complete`?
2. The pull request may stuck because of network issues,I have to press `Ctrl + C`
   to stop the process and run `docker pull jupyter/datascience-notebook` again. Upon this situation,layers which are `Already exists` still shows `Already exists`,but `Pull complete` and `Download complete`layers start to re-download. Does this means that I have to download currently none-existing layers agian even though they are downloaded in a beforehand interrupted pull command?

Comment: If the answer is helpful or for more help. please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The image may have multi-layers. When you pull the image it will download the layers one by one. And if an image layer has existed that it will not pull it again. For more details, see [Images and layers](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/).